# Execute the playwright tests in sequence

Tags: testing, playwright

I have the following directory with test:

[image]

Where inside the "api" folder there is test and inside the "front" folder as well. In the test.ts file I have the following:

[image]

and in the playwright configuration file I have:

[image]

I need the tests in the front folder to run before the api folder, how can I do this?

Comment: It's unclear what's the purpose of test.ts. Generally there should be no difference in which order tests are executed, why is this a problem?

Comment: I am testing a CRUD, so I add an element, edit it and delete it. It is important the order because I can not delete something that is not created for example. For that reason, I need some tests to be executed before others.

Comment: It's not the best but a possible scenario. You need dependent tests to belong to a single test suite, like you tried with test.ts, and make other files like api/ ignored by the runner. Give test suites special names, conventionally test.spec.ts, and filter other files out, https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#filtering-tests . I didn't use playwright's own test runner but it shouldn't differ from others in this regard

Comment: you can use fixtures as well, which is the recommended approach. Your fixture can set up the environment and your test conducts the "edit". You can also determine the [execution order](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures#execution-order)

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), [Run grouped tests sequentially using Playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000771/run-grouped-tests-sequentially-using-playwright), [How to run Playwright spec files in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419841/how-to-run-playwright-spec-files-in-order) and [Playwright docs: control test order](https://playwright.dev/docs/next/test-parallel#control-test-order).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run grouped tests sequentially using Playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000771/run-grouped-tests-sequentially-using-playwright)

Answer (score 0):

You may just simply rename the folders in sequence.

```
1_front
2_api
```